# Sorting a linked list using selection sort in C++

Tags: c++, doubly-linked-list, selection-sort

I'm running into some sort of runtime error when trying to test my sort method. With my implementation, I attempt to find the smallest node in a linked list... Following that I test if the smallest node is first node, last node, or just in the middle. After testing for these cases, I then attempt to add the smallest value into a new linked list. I do this into all the values are sorted, then point head(private variable in my class) to the newly sorted list... If I need to include my header file or anything else, please just let me know. Any help is appreciated.

To be clear, there’s no actual error message, the program just gets terminated when I call my sort function.

```
void Linkedlist::sort()
{
    Node * current = head;
    Node * smallest = head;
    Node * newHead = NULL;
    Node * newTail = NULL;

    while(head != NULL)
    {
        current = head;
        while(current != NULL)
        {
            if(current->elem < smallest->elem)
            {
                smallest = current;
            }
            current = current->next; 
        }

        //smallest is first node
        if(smallest->prev == NULL)
        {
            head = head->next;
            head->prev = NULL;
        }

        //smallest is last node
        else if(smallest->next == NULL)
        {
            tail = tail->prev;
            tail->next = NULL;
        }

        else
        {
            smallest->prev->next = smallest->next;
            smallest->next->prev = smallest->prev;
        }

        //adding smallest to a new linked list
        if(newHead == NULL)
        {
            smallest->prev = NULL;
            smallest->next = NULL;
            newHead = smallest;
        }
        else
        {
            smallest->prev = newTail;
            smallest->next = NULL;
            newTail->next = smallest;
            newTail = smallest;
        }
    }
    //point head to new linked list
    head = newHead;

}
```

Comment: What exactly is going wrong? Is there an error message you could copy into your question?

Comment: @Matt the program just gets terminated when I try to call my sort function. No real error message, that’s why I’m pretty stumped here.

Comment: Have you stepped through it with a debugger?

Comment: @Mark I attempted to use cout lines throughout the the sort function but I never got to see anything output as the program gets terminated. Is what I tried to do the same thing as stepping? If not I’ll look into how to do that.

Comment: So you don't have an IDE like Visual Studio that has an integrated debugger?

Comment: @drescherjm I use netbeans but I have not been using it for long so I’m not too familiar with everything that these kind of IDE can do to help me. I will do some research.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after adding

```
newTail = smallest
```

when putting the smallest element into the first node, and adding

```
smallest = head
```

to the top of my outer while loop, I still was running into an infinite loop. I figured out that for one, I needed to point tail to the newTail at the end by saying

```
tail = newTail
```

After that, my function still caused a segfault. This segfault was due to me trying to access the prev member of a NULL.

```
head = head->next //head is now NULL
head->prev = NULL //segfault
```

This situation occurred when there was only one node was left in the unsorted list. I fixed this issue by adding an if statement inside of the if statement that checks if the smallest is the first node. The if statement inside checked if it was also the final node(aka the last node remaining)

```
//smallest is first node
        if(smallest->prev == NULL)
        {
            //check if smallest is the ONLY node left
            //if it is only node left, head = head->next makes head NULL 
            //                         so then head->prev = NULL causes segfault
            if(smallest->next == NULL)
            {
                //break leaves while loops 
                //which is why you have to add the final node 
                //outside of the while loops
                break;
            }

            else
            {
                head = head->next;
                head->prev = NULL;

            }
        }
```

When there is one node remaining, it will hit the break, and exit both while loops. This means the final node was never added to the sorted list. To fix this I just used the following code before pointing head and tail to their new list.

```
smallest->prev = newTail;
smallest->next = NULL;
newTail->next = smallest;
newTail = smallest;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `newTail` when adding the first element to the new linked list.

Otherwise when `newTail->next = smallest` is executed for the second new entry, it will be a null pointer access.

Just add

```
newTail = smallest
```

after

```
newHead = smallest
```

Comment: just tried adding newTail = smallest at the end of that if statement, and now there is no actual error and it compiles, but it does produce an infinite loop.

Comment: Definitely look into using a debugger, it is much easier to find these types of issues when you can step through the program.

Comment: I think the infinite loop is because you do not set `smallest` to anything in the case where there is only one entry left in the old link list. This means smallest will be left as the last entry that was removed. Add `smallest = head` at the top of your `while head != null)` loop.

Comment: Also please don't edit your code in the question to fix the problem - it means that my answer will no longer make any sense to anyone else.

Comment: Yep, sorry about that. I just went back to my last revision of the post. I added smallest = head to the top of the while loop, and now the program crashes instead of just infinitely looping. I am going to look into how to use netbeans debugger now.